# Converting $X, Y$ on plane to world $X, Y, Z$ coordinates

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vectors, 3d, projective-geometry

I working on program for displaying 3-dimensional objects on the computer screen using Ray Tracing method. And now I came across a problem with throwing rays from the orthogonal camera. So, as you know the orthogonal camera can be defined as a rectangle on some supporting plane and rays are going straight forward from it in the direction of it's normal vector. I made two cycles one inside another for $X$ and $Y$ to scan through that rectangle and throw the rays. And the problem is how to convert coordinates on the plane to coordinates in the global world $X, Y, Z$ space.
I need just to compute the origins of rays.

Sorry for my poor English and incompetence in linear algebra...

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos No one of subjects you listed doesn't matches. I don't know how I should classify my problem.

Comment: I made no mention whatsoever to the classification of your problem.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Sorry, but I can't find something about plane equation or projections in that articles/pages.

Comment: Those pages are about how to put mathematical symbols in your questions, not about Mathematics.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I see. But I think i don't need to put that symbols into my question cause there is not equation or formula in my question or you mean X, Y, Z symbols?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos But the main thing is could you answer my question?